# How to access user claims inside DbContext in .NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I need to apply global query filter on the tables in EF Core on the basis of the role/claim the user have.

Below is my `StartUp.ConfigureServices()` method

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddAuthorization();

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.SaveToken = false;  //TODO: what is this?                
            options.TokenValidationParameters = GetTokenValidationParameters();

            options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
                {                       
                    // Fetch role from jwt and assign it to claim identity.
                    var apiClaims = new ClaimsIdentity();
                    apiClaims.AddClaim(new Claim("role", role.ToString()));
                    ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(apiClaims);
                },
                OnAuthenticationFailed = async ctx =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("************ OnAuthenticationFailed **********");
                    //TODO, do we handle response here?
                }
            };
        });     
        
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        //services
        //      .AddPooledDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(
        //            options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"],
        //            sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(180))
        //      );

        services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>((serviceProvider, optionsBuilder) =>
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(Configuration["ConnectionString"], sqlServerOptions =>
                sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(180)
            );
            optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);
        });        
}
```

MyDbContext.cs

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{   
    private IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
    private List<string> AuthRoleList { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<ElcapitanContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        AuthRoleList = new List<string>();
        _contextAccessor = this.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>();

        AuthRoleList = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Claims.Where(claim => claim.Type == "deptCode")
           .Select(x => x.Value).ToList();   
    }
    
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // ... code emitted for brevity

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasQueryFilter(student => 
                 AuthRoleList.Contains(student.DeptCode));
    }
}
```

Basically, I need to access the claims/role inside the `DbContext` so that I can use it inside `MyDbContext` class.

I have tried with `HttpContextAccessor` but since I am using pooled DB context, the behaviour is not same I guess. When making 4-5 request from different users and browsers, the new context is not created each time so the correct roles are not available inside `DbContext`.

I have also tried creating a scoped service but no luck.

Please help me on this.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found any solution? I'm using ChilliCream's HotChocolate GraphQL server which kinda requires AddPooledDbContextFactory for best performance. I also need to use Global Query Filters for multi-tenancy.

Answer (score 0):

you can inherit your DbContext from IdentityDbContext and access with DbSet.

I have a library that I applied this to. Take a look on [Github](https://github.com/Milvasoft/Milvasoft/blob/master/Milvasoft.Helpers/DataAccess/MilvaContext/MilvaDbContext.cs)

I'm not sure this structure fits on your problem but hope it help.